# How to use Firebase within a Kuberentes cluster

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kubernetes

I am trying to access a Firebase database from inside of a Kubernetes cluster, the only I think of is using a k8s service of type externalName. So I tried with below configuration.

Kuberentes Service:

```
kind : Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata :
  name : firebase-database-service
  labels :
    app : firebase-database-service
  spec:
    type : ExternalName
    externalName : myapp.firebaseio.com
    ports:
      - port : 443
        targetPort: 443
```

And below is my simple node app for demonstration.

```
var firebase        = require('firebase');
var os              = require("os");
var co              = require('co');
var hostName        = os.hostname();

var config = {
    apiKey: "API_KEY",
    databaseURL: "https://firebase-database-service",
};

var dashboard   = firebase.initializeApp(config, 'Dashboard');
dashboard.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("username", "password");
let uid = hostName.split('.').join('_') + "_" + process.pid;
let ref = "/data/"+ uid;

setInterval(co.wrap(function* (){
    try {
        dashboard.database().ref(ref + '/loadavg').set(os.loadavg());
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}), 3000);
```

and I ended up with the below error.

```
FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Cannot parse Firebase url. Please use https://<YOUR FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com 
at Error (native)
at xc (/Users/AAravindan/dev/realtime-screener/projects/test-kube-firebase/node_modules/firebase/database-node.js:55:277)
at yc (/Users/AAravindan/dev/realtime-screener/projects/test-kube-firebase/node_modules/firebase/database-node.js:57:20)
at Object.firebase.INTERNAL.registerService.Reference [as database] (/Users/AAravindan/dev/realtime-screener/projects/test-kube-firebase/node_modules/firebase/database-node.js:255:241)
at P.N (/Users/AAravindan/dev/realtime-screener/projects/test-kube-firebase/node_modules/firebase/app-node.js:18:94)
at Timeout.<anonymous> (/Users/AAravindan/dev/realtime-screener/projects/test-kube-firebase/index.js:19:19)
at next (native)
at onFulfilled (/Users/AAravindan/dev/realtime-screener/projects/test-kube-firebase/node_modules/co/index.js:65:19)
at /Users/AAravindan/dev/realtime-screener/projects/test-kube-firebase/node_modules/co/index.js:54:5
at Timeout.co (/Users/AAravindan/dev/realtime-screener/projects/test-kube-firebase/node_modules/co/index.js:50:10)
```

Is there any way to access firebase from kubernetes cluster.

Here is a sample project if you want to take a look.

[Sample Project](https://github.com/anandanand84/test-kube-firebase)

Comment: What is `https://firebase-database-service`? Is that really the URL you are using? It's not valid. Have you read [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app)?

Comment: @cartant Yes,If you are familiar with kubernetes it is the kubernetes service I have created for firebase. So basically kuberenets will return the alias myapp.firebaseio.com for firebase-database-service during DNS lookup.

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with kubernetes. From what you've described, I think you will have a problem getting this to work, as the error is being raised by the Firebase client checking the URL and being unhappy with it. If you are unable to pass the actual Firebase URL to `initializeApp`, I cannot see a solution.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, I believe it is a bug or a bad design by statically validating the url instead of resolving it through DNS. I have created a bug request with firebase. Lets see what happens

Comment: I don't see the benefit of using a service atop another external one (compared with specifying the url from within your app); but interested to have a clue about this approach. would you mind elaborating ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently(8 Nov 2016) there is no way using the javascript SDK.

I created a bug and here is the reply from the firebase support.

Currently, there is no way to specify the database to be used with the JS SDK other than with the literal URL, with the form: "https://.firebaseio.com", as the error suggests.

Although, I have created a bug regarding this issue and have brought this to the attention of our engineers. I will let you know on this thread for any updates.

Answer (score 0):

Try `kubectl get services`, you'll get your list of service with

```
NAME           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
```

use `CLUSTER-IP` instead of `externalName`

If you still can't connect to your service, run `kubeclt describe <service_name_above>` and check ENTRYPOINT of your service (If your `ENTRYPOINT=<None>`, seem like your service doesn't run normally)
Try to use ENTRYPOINT instead of CLUSTER-IP (not recommend)

Comment: This doesnt work because there is a bug in firebase javascript SDK where the url is validated statically to be in the format https://.firebaseio.com. but kubernetes doesnt accept service name that contains "."

Comment: @anandaravindan +1 thank you for  give me that informations